# Scheme create list of pairs using foldr without explicit recursion

Tags: scheme, racket, fold

I am learning a course of Scheme and have to do the following task. I have to write a function that gets two lists A and B in the same length and returns one list that every item inside is a list of two items - one from A and second from B.
For example the function gets '( 1 2 3) and '(4 5 6) and returns '((1 4)(2 5)(3 6)).
I can do that using map like this:

> (define (func lst1 lst2)   (map (lambda(x y) (list x y)) lst1 lst2))

But the the question is to do that by foldr and **without** explicit recursion.

Can anyone please help me? I have no idea how to do that....
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is knowing what to pass as a function parameter, here's how:

```
(define (func l1 l2)
  (foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc)
           (cons (list e1 e2) acc))
         '()
         l1 l2))
```

Notice that we're passing *two* lists at the end of `foldr`, so the `lambda` expects *three* parameters: the current element from the first list (`e1`), the current element from the second list (`e2`) and the accumulated output (`acc`), which starts with value `'()`. The rest is easy, just build the output along using `cons` and `list`. It works as expected:

```
(func '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> '((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Comment: looks great - can you please explain me what is e1 e2 and acc?

Comment: @RRR I updated my answer: `e1` is the current element from `l1`, `e2` is the current element from `l2` and `acc` is the accumulated result that's returned at the end

Comment: Is there a way to do this with lists of different sizes, where you just ignore the extra information on the longer list? For example, if the lists were '(1 2 3 4) and '(a b c) then the output would be '((1 a) (2 b) (3 c)). I still want to use foldr, but am stuck on an elegant solution or even how to do the ad-hoc case analysis for different sized lists.

Comment: @user2154420 try this: `(define (func l1 l2)
  (let ((minl (min (length l1) (length l2))))
    (foldr (lambda (e1 e2 acc)
             (cons (list e1 e2) acc))
           '()
           (take l1 minl)
           (take l2 minl))))`